# Flutter UI not updating Provider Package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am creating the app where i have used the Provider package at many pages and at all pages its working fine

The issue is i have created the page which show all the business details we add
when we add the UI updated fine. When we tap on that business a new page open and I pass the businessId to that page to get the details of that business on new page
Now the issue is if i add something to that business on new page the UI not update just for the first add i.e(If the employee are empty and i add new employee it show added successfully but UI not update I have to go back and click on that business again to see the change. But after that if add more employee the UI updated perfectly fine without going back)

Maybe i am doing something wrong or missing something can anyone please help me to solve this

Here is my business Class method which create the business on which I tap to open new page:

```
Widget createBusinessWidget(BusinessData businessDataList) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 70,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(20),
            ),
            color: AppColors.backgroudColor1,
          ),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
              child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(5),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: businessDataList.logo!.isEmpty
                      ? ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                          child: Image.asset('assets/noImage.jpg'))
                      : CachedNetworkImage(
                          imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                          ),
                          placeholder: (context, url) => ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius:
                                  const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
                              child: Image.asset('assets/noImage.jpg')),
                          imageUrl: businessDataList.logo.toString(),
                        )),
            ),
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    businessDataList.name,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          SlideLeftPageRoute(
                              page: MyBusinessDetailPage(
                            businessDataId: businessDataList.id,
                          )));
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'View Details',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 10,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: AppColors.mainColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is my new page which opens up new page where i add employees:

```
class MyBusinessDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyBusinessDetailPage({super.key, required this.businessDataId});
  final int businessDataId;

  @override
  State<MyBusinessDetailPage> createState() => _MyBusinessDetailPageState();
}

class _MyBusinessDetailPageState extends State<MyBusinessDetailPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late BusinessData businessDataList;
  late TabController _tabController;
  int _currentIndex = 0;

 
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    businessDataList = ApiResponse().getBusinessById(widget.businessDataId);
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
  }


  void _handleTabSelection() {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = _tabController.index;
    });
  }

  Widget buildCollectionGridItem(Collection collection) {
    bool paid = false;
    String month = CommonData.getCurrentYearAndMonth();
    paid = businessDataList.budget!.any((budget) =>
        budget.month == month &&
        budget.records.any((record) => record.uuid == collection.uuid));
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColors.backgroudColor1,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    collection.name.toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    editCollectionName.text = collection.name.toString();
                    editCollectionDebatorRelation.text =
                        collection.debtorRelation.toString();
                    editCollectionAmmount.text = collection.amount.toString();
                    openModelBottomSheetToEditCollection(context, collection);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.edit,
                    size: 14,
                    color: AppColors.mainColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.calendar_month,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      size: 10,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 3,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      CommonData.getFormattedDate(
                          collection.createdAt.toString()),
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Text(
                  "${UserData().selectedCurrency.split("-").first} ${collection.amount}",
                  style:
                      const TextStyle(color: AppColors.mainColor, fontSize: 10),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: paid
                        ? null
                        : () async {
                            final record = BudgetRecord(
                                uuid: collection.uuid.toString(),
                                type: 'income',
                                label: collection.name.toString(),
                                description:
                                    collection.debtorRelation.toString(),
                                amount: collection.amount.toString(),
                                done: true,
                                createdAt:
                                    DateTime.now().toUtc().toIso8601String(),
                                addedBy: UserData().id,
                                device: Platform.isAndroid ? 'Android' : "IOS",
                                date: DateTime.now().toUtc().toIso8601String(),
                                time: DateTime.now().toUtc().toIso8601String(),
                                updatedAt: "",
                                deletedAt: "");

                            final existingMonthBudget =
                                businessDataList.budget!.firstWhere(
                              (monthBudget) => monthBudget.month == month,
                              orElse: () {
                                final newMonthBudget =
                                    MonthlyBudget(month: month, records: []);
                                businessDataList.budget!.add(newMonthBudget);
                                return newMonthBudget;
                              },
                            );
                            existingMonthBudget.records.add(record);
                            await CommonData
                                .saveBusinessApiResponseToSahredPref(
                                    ApiResponse());
                            rebuild();
                          },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      elevation: 5,
                      backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      "Collect",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(color: AppColors.tabsColor, fontSize: 10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, bottom: 5),
                  child: paid
                      ? const Text(
                          "Collected",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 8),
                        )
                      : const Text(
                          "Not-collected",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: AppColors.expenseColor, fontSize: 8),
                        ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }



  Future<void> addEmployee(String name, String designation, String amount,
      ApiResponse model, StateSetter setState) async {
    bool isValid = employeeForm.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      addingEmployee = true;
    });
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = {
        "business_id": businessDataList.id,
        "name": name,
        "job_title": designation,
        "amount": amount,
      };
      Dio dio = await CommonData.createDioWithAuthHeader();
      Response response =
          await dio.post(CommonData.addEmployessToBusinessApi, data: data);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Map<String, dynamic> responseData = response.data['data'];

        BusinessData businessData = BusinessData.fromJson(responseData);
        if (context.mounted) {
          Provider.of<ApiResponse>(context, listen: false)
              .updateBusiness(businessDataList.id, businessData);
        }
        if (context.mounted) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          setState(() {
            employeeName.clear();
            employeeDesignation.clear();
            employeeAmmount.clear();
            addingEmployee = false;
          });
        }
        if (context.mounted) {
          CommonData.showCustomSnackbar(context, response.data['message']);
          //rebuild();
        }
      }
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      CommonData.sshowDialog(
        'Error',
        e.response!.data['message'],
        context,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
    setState(() {
      addingEmployee = false;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ApiResponse>(builder: (context, model, _) {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: AppColors.backgroudColor2,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
              child: Container(
                height: 45,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 62, 124, 138),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    25.0,
                  ),
                ),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
                  child: TabBar(
                    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                    controller: _tabController,
                    indicator: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                          25.0,
                        ),
                        color: Colors.white),
                    labelColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white24,
                    tabs: const [
                      Tab(
                        text: 'Members',
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        text: 'Employees',
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        text: 'Collections',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                controller: _tabController,
                children: [
                  Center(child:Text('A')),
                  businessDataList.employees!.isEmpty
                      ? const Center(
                          child: Text(
                              "You don't have any employees in your business yet"))
                      : GridView.builder(
                          itemCount: model.businessDataList
                              .firstWhere(
                                  (data) => data.id == businessDataList.id)
                              .employees!
                              .length,
                          gridDelegate:
                              const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                                  crossAxisSpacing: 3.0,
                                  mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                                  childAspectRatio: (1 / .65)),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            print(model.businessDataList
                                .firstWhere(
                                    (data) => data.id == businessDataList.id)
                                .employees!
                                .length);
                            return buildEmployeeGridItem(model.businessDataList
                                .firstWhere(
                                    (data) => data.id == businessDataList.id)
                                .employees![index]);
                          }),
                  Center(child:Text('A'))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        floatingActionButton: _currentIndex == 0
            ? Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => openModelBottomShett(context),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    elevation: 5, backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                    minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(55), // NEW
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    "Add Members",
                    style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.tabsColor),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : _currentIndex == 1
                ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () =>
                          openModelBottomSheetToAddEmployee(context, model),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        elevation: 5, backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                        minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(55), // NEW
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        "Add Employees",
                        style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.tabsColor),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () =>
                          openModelBottomSheetToAddCollection(context),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        elevation: 5, backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                        minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(55), // NEW
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        "Add Collection",
                        style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.tabsColor),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my model class:

```
class Member {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? role;
  String? profilePhoto;
  String? createdAt;

  Member({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.role,
    this.profilePhoto,
    this.createdAt,
  });

  factory Member.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Member(
      id: json['id'] ?? 0,
      name: json['name'] ?? "",
      role: json['role'] ?? "",
      profilePhoto: json['profile_photo'] ?? "",
      createdAt: json['createdAt'] ?? "",
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'role': role,
      'profile_photo': profilePhoto,
      'createdAt': createdAt,
    };
  }
}

class Employee {
  String? name;
  String? uuid;
  int? amount;
  String? jobTitle;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  String? description;

  Employee({
    this.name,
    this.uuid,
    this.amount,
    this.jobTitle,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.description,
  });

  factory Employee.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Employee(
      name: json['name'],
      uuid: json['uuid'],
      amount: json['amount'],
      jobTitle: json['job_title'],
      createdAt: json['created_at'],
      updatedAt: json['updated_at'],
      description: json['description'],
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'uuid': uuid,
      'amount': amount,
      'job_title': jobTitle,
      'created_at': createdAt,
      'updated_at': updatedAt,
      'description': description,
    };
  }
}

class Collection {
  String? name;
  String? uuid;
  int? amount;
  String? reminder;
  bool? recurring;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  String? description;
  String? debtorRelation;

  Collection({
    this.name,
    this.uuid,
    this.amount,
    this.reminder,
    this.recurring,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.description,
    this.debtorRelation,
  });

  factory Collection.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Collection(
      name: json['name'],
      uuid: json['uuid'],
      amount: json['amount'],
      reminder: json['reminder'],
      recurring: json['recurring'],
      createdAt: json['created_at'],
      updatedAt: json['updated_at'],
      description: json['description'],
      debtorRelation: json['debtor_relation'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'uuid': uuid,
      'amount': amount,
      'reminder': reminder,
      'recurring': recurring,
      'created_at': createdAt,
      'updated_at': updatedAt,
      'description': description,
      'debtor_relation': debtorRelation,
    };
  }
}


class Participant {
  String? name;
  String? relation;
  int? remainingAmount;
  String? type;
  String? uuid;

  Participant({
    this.name,
    this.relation,
    this.remainingAmount,
    this.type,
    this.uuid,
  });

  factory Participant.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>? json) {
    if (json == null) {
      return Participant();
    }

    return Participant(
      name: json['name'],
      relation: json['relation'],
      remainingAmount: json['remainingAmount'],
      type: json['type'],
      uuid: json['uuid'],
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'relation': relation,
      'remainingAmount': remainingAmount,
      'type': type,
      'uuid': uuid,
    };
  }
}


class ApiResponse extends ChangeNotifier {
  static final ApiResponse _instance = ApiResponse._internal();
  List<BusinessData> businessDataList;

  factory ApiResponse() {
    return _instance;
  }

  ApiResponse._internal() : businessDataList = [];

  void initializeData(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (businessDataList.isEmpty) {
      List<dynamic> businessDataJsonList = json['data'];
      businessDataList = businessDataJsonList
          .map((businessDataJson) => BusinessData.fromJson(businessDataJson))
          .toList();
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'businessDataList':
          businessDataList.map((data) => data.toJson()).toList(),
    };
  }

  factory ApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse._internal();
    List<dynamic> businessDataJsonList = json['businessDataList'];
    apiResponse.businessDataList = businessDataJsonList
        .map((businessDataJson) => BusinessData.fromJson(businessDataJson))
        .toList();
    return apiResponse;
  }

  void addBusinessData(BusinessData businessData) {
    businessDataList.add(businessData);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<BusinessData> getBusinessDataForMyBusiness() {
    return businessDataList
        .where((data) => data.userId == UserData().id)
        .toList();
  }

  List<BusinessData> getBusinessDataForMyAccess() {
    return businessDataList
        .where(
            (data) => data.members!.any((member) => member.id == UserData().id))
        .toList();
  }

  void updateBusiness(int businessId, BusinessData updatedBusiness) {
    final index = businessDataList.indexWhere((data) => data.id == businessId);

    if (index != -1) {
      businessDataList[index] = updatedBusiness;
      notifyListeners(); 
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addEmployeeToBusiness(BusinessData businessData, Employee employee) {
    businessData.employees!.add(employee);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  BusinessData getBusinessById(int businessId) {
    return businessDataList.firstWhere(
      (data) => data.id == businessId,
    );
  }
}

class Owner {
  int? id;
  String? name;

  int? plan;

  String? selectedCurrency;
  String? profilePhoto;


  Owner({
    this.id,
    this.name,

    this.plan,

    this.selectedCurrency,
    this.profilePhoto,

  });

  factory Owner.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Owner(
      id: json['id'] ?? 0,
      name: json['name'] ?? "",

      plan: json['plan'] ?? 0,

      selectedCurrency: json['selected_currency'] ?? "\$ - USD",
      profilePhoto: json['profile_photo'] ?? "",

    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'plan': plan,
      'selected_currency': selectedCurrency,
      'profile_photo': profilePhoto,
    };
  }
}



class BusinessData {
  int id;
  int? userId;
  String name;
  String category;
  String? logo;
  String? description;
  Owner? owner;
  List<Member>? members;
  List<Employee>? employees;
  List<Collection>? collection;
  List<MonthlyBudget>? budget;

  BusinessData({
    required this.id,
    this.userId,
    required this.name,
    required this.category,
    this.logo,
    required this.description,
    this.owner,
    this.members,
    this.employees,
    this.collection,
    this.budget,
  });

  factory BusinessData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return BusinessData(
        id: json['id'],
        userId: json['user_id'] ?? 0,
        name: json['name'],
        category: json['category'],
        logo: json['logo'] ?? '',
        description: json['description'] ?? '',
        owner: Owner.fromJson(json['owner'] ?? {}),
        members: List<Member>.from(
          json['members'].map((budgetData) => Member.fromJson(budgetData)),
        ),
        employees: List<Employee>.from(
          json['employees'].map((budgetData) => Employee.fromJson(budgetData)),
        ),
        collection: List<Collection>.from(
          json['collections']
              .map((budgetData) => Collection.fromJson(budgetData)),
        ),
        budget: List<MonthlyBudget>.from(
          json['budget']
              .map((budgetData) => MonthlyBudget.fromJson(budgetData)),
        ));
  }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a businessDataList in your Provider (in your ApiResponse class as I see).

First, define a Provider variable and assign it in didChangeDependencies() method in MyBusinessDetailPage:

```
late ApiResponse _apiResponse;

@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
    final apiResponse = Provider.of<ApiResponse>(context);
    if (this._apiResponse != apiResponse) {
      this._apiResponse = apiResponse;
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Then, in addEmployee() function, change the code block that updates the business list like this:

```
if (context.mounted) {
  _apiResponse
      .updateBusiness(businessDataList.id, businessData);
}
```

I think this method updates the businessDataList. I normally use it like this, so it should work. And don't forget to use the businessDataList in the Provider to update the data and UI.

Comment: No this didn't work instead it showing error widget to rebuild unnecessarily, leading to this assertion failure

Comment: You are getting your businessDataList from Provider, right? Then maybe you need to define your Provider in didChangeDependencies() method of the state. I'm gonna update the answer.

Comment: I tried but still not updating the UI :-(

Comment: final int businessDataId this the id i am gotten from previous page and then   late BusinessData businessDataList;
initState method businessDataList = ApiResponse().getBusinessById(widget.businessDataId);

then i want to update the UI when data changes

Comment: You can put the businessDataList in ApiResponse class, or a better way, you can create a new Provider class called BusinessProvider and put the businessDataList there. Then you can update your list in BusinessProvider using ApiResponse, and use it in your UI.